# My Foundation Icons are not working in Firefox. Only letters in a box display instead

Tags: firefox, zurb-foundation, foundation-icon-fonts

[image: My Search Button with a broken icon]

The Html

```
<link rel=stylesheet href=../static/css/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css>

<a class="button radius search-header"><i class="fi-magnifying-glass"></i> Search</a>
```

I have navigated to foundation-icons.css after hitting Ctrl+U within Firefox so I am definitely linking to the file correctly.

I have copied the foundation-icons folder exactly and not removed anything. It looks like this:

```
./static/css/foundation-icons/
 - foundation-icons.css
 - foundation-icons.eot
 - foundation-icons.svg
 - foundation-icons.ttf
 - foundation-icons.woff
 - svgs/*
 - preview.html
```

Edit: I have changed the title and added the Firefox tag because everything seems to be working fine in Chromium. I am a little stumped because that means it's a Firefox issue and probably not possible for me to fix.

The preview.html file that comes with foundation-icons works correctly in my Firefox as well.

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the `SCSS` files, you should point the `$fi-path` variable to the correct location of your `foundation-icon-fonts` folder.

For me I had to add the following before importing `foundation-icon-fonts`:

```sass
$fi-path: 'foundation-icon-fonts';
```

Answer (score 0):

First correct this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css">`

In examples of Foundation, Firefox use `.woff` files. Check if you have access to them.

It's a relative path. Are you sure 'static' folder is reachable with your browser ?

Comment: Yes it is. Like I said I navigated to the actual css files from within firefox to check if it works. I just checked with an absolute path and it is the same deal. Also since the icon renders in Chromium I can assume all paths are correct.